# service stops after closing powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm running a command in powershell

```
blockchain-wallet-service start  --port 3000
```

output looks like this

```
159243453597 - info: blockchain.info wallet service v0.26.3 running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

which occupies cli and prevents from running other commands after.
I created a new windows service using **New-Service** and it autostarts on reboot. BUT it doesn't respond to windows after it starts and windows shuts it down since it thinks it's dead. But it actually works the problem is  the output. it just stays on

```
info: blockchain.info wallet service v0.26.3 running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Forever. How do I go around it?

Comment: You cant run Start-Job outside of powershell... if you exit the program running workers, all workers will exit since they depend on the program to function.

Comment: the same happens in cmd, process stops once cmd is closed.

Comment: Have you tried running what you are trying to do as a windows service ?

Comment: Yes, but after short period of time Windows shuts it down since it doesn't receive any response.  When command is running it gives output to the console that it's listening on a port that's why it never responds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed service using NSSM.

**Powershell_script.ps1**

```
$serviceName = 'MyService'
nssm install $serviceName "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\blockchain-wallet-service.cmd" "start"
nssm status $serviceName
Start-Service $serviceName
Get-Service $serviceName
```

Documentation used: [git.nssm](https://git.nssm.cc/nssm/nssm)  [gist.nssm](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/2217fd95cf15a0324696)  [nssm.cc](https://nssm.cc/usage)

P.S. Unfortunately I couldn't install it using **New-Service** option, as blockchain-wallet-service never response back to the windows service as I understood...